# Buffer overflow buffer length

Tags: c, perl, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I have a buffer overflow problem that I need to solve. Below is the problem, at the bottom is my question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void lan(void) {
   printf("Your loyalty to your captors is touching.\n");
}

void vulnerable(char *str) {
   char buf[LENGTH]; //Length is not given
   strcpy(buf, str); //str to fixed size buf (uh-oh)
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) 
       return -1;
    vulnerable(argv[1]);
    return 0;
 }

 (gdb) disass vulnerable
 0x08048408: push %ebp
 0x08048409: mov %esp, %ebp
 0x0804840b: sub $0x88, %esp
 0x0804840e: mov 0x8(%ebp), %eax
 0x08048411: mov %eax, 0x4(%esp)
 0x08048415: lea -0x80(%ebp), %eax
 0x08048418: mov %eax, (%esp)
 0x0804841b: call 0x8048314 <strcpy>
 0x08048420: leave
 0x08048421: ret
 End of assembler dump.

 (gdb) disass lan
  0x080483f4:   push %ebp
  0x080483f5:   mov %esp, %ebp
  0x080483f7:   sub $0x4, %esp
  0x080483fa:   movl $0x8048514, (%esp)
  0x08048401:   call 0x8048324 <puts>
  0x08048406:   leave
  0x08048407:   ret
  End of assembler dump.
```

Then we have the following info:

```
 (gdb) break *0x08048420
 Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048420
 (gdb) run 'perl -e' print "\x90" x Length' 'AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE'
 Breakpoint 1, 0x08048420 in vulnerable
 (gdb) info reg $ebp
 ebp          0xffffd61c 0xffffd61c
 (gdb) # QUESTION: Where in memory does the buf buffer start?
 (gdb) cont
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

And finally, the perl command is a shorthand for writing out LENGTH copies of the character 0x90.

I've done a couple of problems of this sort before, but what stops me here is the following question: "By looking at the assembly code, what is the value of LENGTH?"

I'm not sure how to find that from the given assembly code. What I do know is.. the buffer that we're writing into is on the stack at the location -128(%ebp) (where -128 is a decimal number). However, I'm not sure where to go from here to get the length of the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your `vulnerable` function.

First the compiler creates a frame and reserves 0x88 bytes on the stack:

```
 0x08048408: push %ebp
 0x08048409: mov %esp, %ebp
 0x0804840b: sub $0x88, %esp
```

Then it puts two values onto the stack:

```
 0x0804840e: mov 0x8(%ebp), %eax
 0x08048411: mov %eax, 0x4(%esp)
 0x08048415: lea -0x80(%ebp), %eax
 0x08048418: mov %eax, (%esp)
```

And the last thing it does before returning is calling `strcpy(buf, str)`:

```
 0x0804841b: call 0x8048314 <strcpy>
 0x08048420: leave
 0x08048421: ret
```

So we can deduce that the two values it put on the stack are the arguments to `strcpy`.
`mov 0x8(%ebp)` would be `char *str` and `lea -0x80(%ebp)` would be a pointer to `char buf[LENGTH]`.

Therefore, we know that your buffer starts at `-0x80(%ebp)`, so it has a length of 0x80 = 128 bytes assuming the compiler didn't waste any space.

Answer (score 1):

> What I do know is.. the buffer that we're writing into is on the stack
>   at the location -128(%ebp)

Since the local variables end at `%ebp`, and you only have a single local variable which is `buffer` itself, you can conclude that it has length at most `128`. It may be shorter, if the compiler added some padding for alignment.

Comment: Thanks @Jester, that's what I thought (which stopped me from answering the question). It is a question from an old exam at my school, and I felt (and still feel like) it is odd to answer how big LENGTH is when I don't know how much padding the compiler placed in there.